# Returning a list of users based on column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a grid of data where each row is a used and each column is a product type they have purchased, here is a trimmer version, the full table has over 200 columns:

```
UserID  total   purchase_range  tshirts jeans   jumpers shoes   scarves belts   hats    coats   chinos  socks
a3470c41-d349-4f5c-bd2d-ed58d2959758    1   Narrow  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
02dbb049-f28e-4637-9e35-3bce06b65727    1   Narrow  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9803c98a-890c-4b99-b32a-f34658b1bddd    1   Narrow  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5e19940d-d981-4e42-900c-242687d37ae0    1   Narrow  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
8cf37896-b675-491e-a06a-6282966d8a43    1   Narrow  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
931f63a1-456f-4ff4-b0c5-4474a5e4a75d    1   Narrow  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
552b12dc-5ea1-49d1-ab08-9b7c688df03c    1   Narrow  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
bbe5d4f5-8b32-44a3-bb89-eed8304111e7    1   Narrow  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
09d15874-1cdc-43aa-9761-a3287faed610    1   Narrow  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9825692b-912b-45e1-b3ae-f18d7eda8700    1   Narrow  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
030dccda-7de2-4293-aee6-ad079f6f0feb    1   Narrow  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4388651d-041a-45d8-b7fe-1894003ce4f2    1   Narrow  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
06c643f3-b93b-49df-974a-8d5c2cf97e8b    1   Narrow  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6a6f0f75-5970-470f-b1f5-a299a26e0468    1   Narrow  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
62739f9f-e1aa-4139-b26e-0df8679aee3d    1   Narrow  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4d0605b5-b043-466c-a13c-17a17b6a7ba8    1   Narrow  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9d6e6eba-53c2-4f23-ab25-3c169c35cf2f    1   Narrow  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

What would be the best way to return a list of userIds who had purchased a particular product type or combinations of them? Would I need to establish a blank list for each category, then iterate over it with a for loop to count the number of '1's in that column? If so how can I return the actual userids rather than a count? Is there a more elegant/flexible way to do this?

Comment: Your table is unreadable. When you print a dataframe in Python it does the alignment for you. you can even tell if it should print all the rows or just the first 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way. The advantage of this method is you can provide an arbitrary combination of products to check.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'UserID': {0: 'a3470c41-d349-4f5c-bd2d-ed58d2959758',
                              1: '02dbb049-f28e-4637-9e35-3bce06b65727',
                              2: '9803c98a-890c-4b99-b32a-f34658b1bddd'},
                   'belts': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1},
                   'chinos': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0},
                   'coats': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1},
                   'hats': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 0},
                   'jeans': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0},
                   'jumpers': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1},
                   'purchase_range': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0},
                   'scarves': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0},
                   'shoes': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0},
                   'socks': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0},
                   'tshirts': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 1}})

def get_ids(lst):
    return df.loc[np.logical_and.reduce([df[i] for i in lst]), 'UserID'].tolist()

get_ids(['tshirts', 'hats'])

# ['a3470c41-d349-4f5c-bd2d-ed58d2959758']
```

Comment: Excellent, many thanks, is it possible to sue this method to run against 2 dataframes? I'd like to expand this with another data set for users who have only viewed product categories, then query users who have, for example, viewed jeans and purchased socks. Would it be best to merge the dataframes and if so how might I perform such a query?

Comment: Yes, for efficiency I suggest merging dataframes before the query.

Answer (score 2):

Just use standard boolean logic and indexing:

For a combination of shoes and jeans:

```
indices = (df['shoes'] > 0) & (df['jeans'] > 0)
print(df['userid'][indices])
```

Output:

```
dtype: bool
0    <some-id>
2    <other-id>
Name: userid, dtype: int64
```

(That output is a `Series`. Use `df['userid'][indices].values` to get just a numpy array with pure indices.)